# How to set only AM time for an UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios

Right now I am using an `UIDatePicker` with mode set to `Time` only. So I can choose between AM and PM time.

Is there a way to prevent choosing PM time ? My app is using a morning routine so there is no point on selecting PM time.

At least I want to always show an AM time, right now it displays the current time (so if it's PM, I have to change it to AM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the date picker's `minimumDate` to midnight and its `maximumDate` to noon. Also, if (as you say) it is currently after noon, set the date picker's `date` to 12 hours earlier.